# How to use accelerometer to detect vibration / motion on Blackberry Java

Tags: blackberry, java-me, accelerometer

i want to make Step Counter in Blackberry OS 7. I want my app count every user motion. But i don't know how to detect vibration / motion using Accelerometer like SensorEvent in Android. Anybody can help me ?